# Shorthand IF statement in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, ternary

I'm wondering if the following is possible. I want the if statement that I wrote below to be in one line (ternary).

I want to use the ternary(shorthand php code) in a array for cURL.

Form data example:

```
$_POST['data'] = 'sometextrighthereisgood:this is what we want"; //user input example.
```

If statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{
$string = explode(':', $_POST['data']);
$string = $string[1]; //contains "this is what we want"
}
else
{
$string = NULL;
}
```

Array example:

```
$arr = array('text' => $string); //example for use in the array.
```

Any ideas if it's possible?

Kind Regards Alex

Comment: Ternary operator isn't a shorthand if.

Comment: You are confused about Ternary, a `:` in a string (your `$_POST`) has no special meaning

Comment: "I want the if statement that I wrote below to be in one line " --- because... ?

Comment: What is the name for an shorthand if statement, then?

I explode the string $_POST every time it finds the charater ":".
There will always (in my case) only be one ":".
I actually just want the "this is what we want". And then add it to the key in the array.

Comment: @Alex: there is no a shorthand `if` statement. Ternary operator isn't even close to `if`

Comment: @zerkms ...
I could go with multiple line version (normal if-statement). But the thing I'm coding only uses single line if statement. I just want it to be the same as the others. And it's a challenge.

Comment: "And it's a challenge" --- the art of programming is to know how to write readable and maintainable code, not the tricky oneliners.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
list(,$string) = isset($_POST['data']) 
               ? explode(':', $_POST['data']) 
               : array(null,null)
               ;
```

Comment: You may just omit the first variable in `list()` -- `list(,$string)`

Comment: PS: not about this exact answer (which is terribly correct, +1) but to the OP: this solution is awful. The original code is million times more readable

Comment: Nice solution... way better than mine (except for the sanity of $_POST['data'])... But I still don't understand what is the problem with `if`.

Comment: I came up with this: `$foo = isset($_POST['data']) && (list($want,$dontwant) = explode(":",$_POST['data'])) ? $dontwant : null;`

Comment: @Alex: and what if `$foo` for?

Comment: @zerkms nothing actually. :)

Comment: A bit older method, but works:
`$value = isset($_POST['data']) && stristr(':',$_POST['data']) ? substr($_POST['data'],0,strpos($_POST['data'],':')) : null;`

Comment: @Alex: "nothing actually." -- and you still think it's better than just `if`?

Comment: @zerkms I never said that an IF was worse! I just wanted to see if it could be done. I was just curious :)

Answer (score 1):

IMO micro optimisations like this will make your code un-readable, and what happens if no `:` is contained within the string then you will get an `Undefined index` when attempting to read from that array index.

If you are not 100% sure a value is what you expect you need to check it. You could do sub ternary checks but is it worth it?

```
<?php
$data = 'sometextrighthereisgood:this is what we want';

if(isset($data)){
    $string = explode(':',$data);
    $string = isset($string[1]) ? $string[1] : NULL;
}else{
    $string = NULL;
}
echo $string; //this is what we want
?>
```

Comment: Remove extra parentheses around the ternary operator expression and add several spaces there - and it would be an ideal answer

Comment: `$test = $string ? $string = explode(':', $string) AND $string[1] : NULL;`

But this only tell me true or false.

Comment: @Alex: http://php.net/ternary - read the documentation of a proper syntax finally, please. Writing *random* code and expecting it to work - isn't a good idea ever

Comment: Okay, so I should avoid the ternary in this case because it dosen't make sense. Why does everybody on the internet say the it's an shorthand if-statement then. Well i acts like an if. But should only be used in true or false environments. Right??

Comment: @Alex ternarys are fine for defining variables like `$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : NULL;` so as not to hit thos Undefined variable warnings and in most cases can shorten the code for the initial define stage, but if you want todo logic/manipulation on a string like passing it through a function, then its not really suited and can lead to the same amount of code for the same operation but slightly un-readable. Dont get me wrong I love em... my2cent

Comment: What about the PHP-compiler (or what you want to call it). What is faster an if-statement or an ternary for a simple usage?

Answer (score 0):

You have one problem with your code. After explode, if there is no ":" in the original string, PHP may show a notice or error on the line:

```
$string = $string[1]
```

As `$string[1]` may not be defined. So, you can check it before assigning:

```
$string = (sizeof($string) >= 2 ? $string[1] : null);
```

Other solution, is to [ignore the notice message](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

```
$string =@ $string[1]
```

Which, as zerkms said, is an ugly solution and a bad practice, as you don't have too much control (because it ignore any level of error, notice, etc.). So, avoid it.

And, for the `if` issue. I personally think that is perfectly fine to use the way you used, it is cleaner and easier to understand. Anyway, with ternary you could use something like:

```
$string = (isset($_POST['data']) ? explode(':', $_POST['data'], 2) : null);
$string = ($string != null && sizeof($string) >= 2 ? $string[1] : null);
```

Comment: "A simple solution would be to ignore the error:" --- -1,   `s/simple/stupid/`

Comment: My string will always contain the ":" with data in front and after it, since the user can't effect it in anyway.

Comment: @zerkms, that why I gave a better solution. Did you read it all?

Comment: @Alex, Are you sure? Seems that it is a POST data, and people can **ALWAYS** send whatever he/she wants through HTTP POST. In case of validation, you can check it before, and, if wrong, show an error to the user.

Comment: @Matheus de Oliveira: I did read. But `@` doesn't deserve to even being mentioned. I don't even say that you mentioned it first and labelled as a "simple"

Comment: @zerkms, disagreed. The `@` is ugly (I never use it actually), that I agree. But I think we may show as much possibilities as possible, and tell which one is better/safer/prettier/etc.

Comment: @MatheusOl: still - it's not a good idea to put it first and call it "simplest". Newbies never choose the best practices, they choose the easy to use solutions

Comment: @zerkms, ok, you won... changing the way I wrote it to clarify.